# Deserializing complex string

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Here is my Class

```
class Respondents
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Seed { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> Answers { get; set; }

    public Respondents()
    {
        Answers = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    }       
}
```

And i m trying to deserialize it using below code-:

```
 string jsonResp = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\JsonOutputFiles\Sample Survey.json");
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Respondents>(jsonResp);
```

I am not able to do it.Need your views and advice

Comment: What are the problems you've ran into?

Comment: Can you post the JSON text as well. When you said not able to do it, do you get an error? If so what is it?

Comment: {
  "ID": "Resp1",
  "Version": "Version",
  "Status": "Partial",
  "Seed": 1,
  "Start": "DateTime",
  "End": "DateTime",
  "Duration": "Seconds",
  "Answers": {
    "Q1": {
      "Value": "test@123.com"
    },
    "Q2": {
      "Value": 20
    },
    "Q3": {
      "Value": null
    },
    "Q4": {
      "Value": "5"
    },
    "Q5": {
      "Value": 100
    },
    "Q6": {
      "Value": [
        "3",
        "4"
      ]
    },
    "Q7": {
      "Value": null
    },
    "Q8": {
      "Value": [
        "4",
        "5",
        "8"
      ]
    },
    "Q9": {
      "Value": null
    }
  }
}

Comment: yes it gives me error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like array or List<T>) that can be deserialized frm JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'Answers.Q1.Value',line 11,position 15

Comment: I'm sorry, but the exception couldn't be more descriptive. Your JSON doesn't match your C# model. I suggest you look at it more closely. Hint: It is in the Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your json is that `Value` may contain `int`, `string` or `string array`. Even you go the dynamic way as said in other answer, you should check the value(whether it is array or not) before using it.

I would write a json converter, and convert all the values to `List<string>`

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Respondents>(jsonResp);
```

---

```
public class Val
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringArrayConverter))]
    public List<string> Value { set; get; }
}

public class Respondents
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Seed { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,Val> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class StringArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.ValueType == typeof(long))
        {
            return new List<string>() { reader.Value.ToString() };
        }

        if (reader.ValueType == typeof(string))
        {
            return new List<string>() { (string)reader.Value };
        }
        return serializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: An additional approach which can help is to have your class bound with DataMember attributes on some private fields that are objects and then have the logic of your public property's get accessor test for whether  it is of type string, integer, string[] etc

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the dynamic type to deserialize it?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonResp);
```

I don't think your input JSON suits a C# model at runtime due to the 'array' style keys that are being applied to the "Answers" Dictionary - eg; Q1, Q2, Q3

Also I would normally use the DataContract attribute on my class and the DataMember attribute on my members to indicate that there is a need for serialization.